# How to validate .NET Framework 4.8 is installed on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, net

I installed .NET Framework 4.8 on a Windows Server 2016 using this link .NET 4.8 offline installer][1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0). And although everything seems to be going well, when I check the windows features it does not appear installed and 4.6 is displayed. Please, could you tell me what I do wrong?

```
[X] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev                    Installed
        [X] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext                    Installed
        [X] .NET Extensibility 4.6                  Web-Net-Ext45                  Installed
        [X] Application Initialization              Web-AppInit                    Installed
        [X] ASP                                     Web-ASP                        Installed
        [X] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net                    Installed
        [X] ASP.NET 4.6
```

My guessing is that I should look for something like this:

[image: Net 4.8]

Comment: Windows Features lists some versions of .net; but this is confusing; it's not showing all possible/all installed versions; only those versions which it can install (I believe those specific versions get bundled as Windows Features as they're required by many other Windows components).  To see what versions of .Net you have installed, you can use this handy program: http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is something not working, you should provide that instead of assuming that the Windows Feature dialog would change.

You may query the registry to determine the version of .NET Framework installed:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Release
```

If the value is 528040 (decimal) (0x80EA8 hex) or higher, .NET 4.8 is installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Answer (score 2):

Under what logic would you expect installing what is IIRC an in place upgrade (4.8) to change the name of a windows feature THAT INSTALLERS MAY RELY UPON?

It makes sense to not change that unless you introduce breaking changes - which 4.8 is designed not to do.

Comment: I have an application that we have migrated to 4.8. So, shouldn't I install 4.8 and has this appear in Windows Features? Currently is not working.

Comment: YOu should intall it - but you should not expect the windows feature to change the name. Use the registry to find out what versions of he. NET runtime are installed.

Comment: I added a picture for the thing I suppose I should looking for. What is your opinion about that?